# Difference between Open and Create on DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, openxml, openxml-sdk

The docs for both methods read virtually identical to me. I have a template (.DOTX) which I want to open and make changes to, saving as .DOCX. What's the right approach? And, in fact, how *do* I save the document? I see no Save method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Open` method requires that the document already exists.  If not, an exception is thrown.

Using the `Create` method will open the document if it exists or create it if it doesn't.

When you call the `Close` method, the document is saved automatically.

Comment: The weird thing is that using 'Open' does create the file if is not exist and then throws the exception. Who asked you to create the file!!?